# Android upload sketches to Arduino using AVRDUDE through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, avrdude

I would like to use a bluetooth serial link on my Android device to upload .hex files to my arduino UNO board.
I successufully load arduino sketches from Android using AVRDude command:
/myFolders/avrdude -settings -serialPort -configuration -fileToBeFlashed.

My serialPort is /dev/ttyACM0 while the arduino is connected to USB. This works fine. 
However, when the bluetooth adapter is connected, I receive the error "programmer is not responding".
I cannot identfy on which port is bluetooth running. I tried to enumerate the serial ports but I can't find any difference with or without the bluetooth adapter.
Any idea on where to find the right serial port name for bluetooth communication?

Comment: What bluetooth module you use on arduino side? If ble than it may put you into trouble. Also you may need init Bt on arduino before use it for programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try reset your board (but not bluetooth) right before programming. You maybe noticed that board resets every time serial port is activated. First time after reset bootloader is active, if no, it starts user program.

If you look at board scheme you can find there reset signal (pin) connected to programming chip on legal boards, or to usb-serial converter on clones. This done for resetting the board after usart opening.

Some bluetooth modules have a pin indicating connection state, it maybe helpful to connect the pin to arduinos's reset.

Comment: Unfortunately this has nothing to do with reset. I am aware about the need of resetting the board prior uploading the sketch but in first instance I noticed that a connection is not established between the bluetooth adapter on the tablet and the bluetooth module on the arduino side. I am using a rooted tablet, so I do have access to all the possible configuration settings. I need to know how to specify a bluetooth serial port RFComm on my tablet in order to start the communication. Any ideas?